# Move react component to another parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently creating a chessgame in React for learning purposes. What i'm running into is moving a React component from one parent to another parent, keeping the props. I've read about ReactDOM.createPortal(), but i can't seem to get it working.

To illustrate the problem i've created a simple React app with two containers, where one container has a button in it. The goal is to move the button to the other container when it's clicked.

```
export default class ParentLeft extends React.Component{

  render(){
    return(
      <div className="container">
        <Button />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default class ParentRight extends React.Component{

  render(){
    return(
      <div className="container"></div>
    );
  }
}
```

In this example the simple solution will be calling a function in the ParentRight component and using setState() to render a Button component in it. This is not the solution i'm looking for. In my chessgame i don't know what kind of React component needs to be moved.

Comment: Why don't you just create a component with the button in it, and show it in either the left or right component?

Comment: This is just for example purposes. In my app there are squares in the chessboard, and when a user moves a piece(could be a tower, a queen, e.t.c) the react component needs to be moved from one square to another one, keeping the props.

Comment: I think the way to keep it simple is to create a class with state in it (such as the cells on the board) and tell the 'parent' to display a specific cell. This way you don't need to keep track of the props, but just to show whats inside the cell. Is this something you could use? Basically what @hammeramr says, but you don't have to use a Redux store specifically.

Comment: You would render the button based on some condition. So like `{this.state.activeButton == 1 && <Button />}`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Then the props could be passed to the new component, but still the square still doesn't know if it should render a <Queen/> of a <King /> component. Or am i overlooking something?

Comment: @WebdevE Example: https://jsfiddle.net/tsy0ez1v/

Comment: Think about using drag & drop functions to really move your component.

Comment: @Caramiriel Thank you. That will definetely work, but isn't there a way to actually move the component rather then making a new element and passing the props and attributes?

Answer (score 0):

Top component named `container` must have all the state which define figures and its places. Let it be the `Bridge` component:

```js
class Bridge = () => {
  const figures = useState()
  const squares = useState()
  render board.each(square =>
    <Square figure={figure[square]}>
  )
}
```

Create component `Square`:

```
class Square = ({figure}) => {
  render (
    <Figure figure={figure}>
  )
}
```

Create component `Figure`:

```
class Figure = ({figure}) => {
  render switch(figure) {
    case 'king': return <King/>
    case 'queen': return <Quieen/>
    default: return null
  )
}
```

So now if you need button for square only if square have a figure you can make square like this:

```js
class Square = ({figure}) => {
  render (`
    <React.Fragment>
      <Figure figure={figure}>
      {figure ? <Button> : null}
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Use same approach for your `ParenLeft` and `ParentRight`. Or create generalized `Parent` component. And use it like this `<Paren left/>` or `<Paren right/>`. See `Figure` about how to use conditions.

You can not use `ReactDOM.createPortal()` to render something from one place of react tree to another - because portal is another additional react tree. To render something from one react place to another react place you need [react-through](https://github.com/oklas/react-through/)

Comment: If there doesn't exist anything like moveComponent, i think this is the best way.

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion is for you is to rethink the flow of your program. Usually, without the help of context and/or redux or other state-managers, you don’t see unrelated components talking to each other. By unrelated components we can define them as those who do not share a relatively close common ancestor, e.g. a wrapper component controlling its props.children with a state.

Though I believe you could achieve the result you want with Portals, they are usually used to render modals and similar components such as dialogs, messages, etc.

With those facts in mind, the recommended approach, which follows the top-to-bottom flow suggested by Facebook, is this:

```js
export default class MainWrapper extends React.Component {
  state = {
    buttonAtLeft: true,
  }

  changeButtonPosition = () => {
    this.setState({ buttonAtLeft: !this.state.buttonAtLeft });
  }

  render() {
    const { buttonAtLeft } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <ParentLeft>
          {
            buttonAtLeft
              ? <Button onClick={this.changeButtonPosition} />
              : undefined
          }
        </ParentLeft>
        <ParentRight>
          {
            buttonAtLeft
              ? undefined
              : <Button onClick={this.changeButtonPosition} />
          }
        </ParentRight>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Just remember to update the ParentRight/Left component, make them render the props.children on their render method:

```js
render() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      {this.props.children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Explanation:

The MainWrapper is now responsible for changing the position of the button, and it also serves as a bridge exchanging communication between both ParentLeft and ParentRight. Its method changeButtonPosition simply toggles the boolean buttonAtLeft, which is found in MainWrapper’s state.

Subsequently, we do a conditional render based on the state.buttonAtLeft, rendering the button on its appropriated place.